# How to find words out of an string using arrays Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I need to find all 4,5,6 letter words in a string of letters. When we find each for letter word, we are then supposed asked to check if the word is in the English dictionary.

The problem I am facing is that I am not sure how I can make java find all 4,5,6 letter words?

The example they gave us is like this:

```
String letter = "fourgooddogsswam";

int wordSize = 4;
```

Then the words are:

```
four
ourg
urgo
rgoo
good
oodd
oddo
ddog
dogs
ogss
gssw
sswa
swam
```

In reality, the only words are four, good, dogs, swam.

Again, I am wondering how to make a loop or something of that nature in order to find all of the four letter words. Any help or tips are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty simple algorithm and if you are taking classes of basic programing is better way take time to think about and learn than use forums to answer your homework

```
for(int i = 0; i < letter.length()-4;i++){

    fourLetter = letter.substring(i,i+4);
    //... do whatever you want
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First You need to split the string of size 4.By using below code you will get array of String having length 4.

```
List<String> elementList = new ArrayList<String>();

 for(int i = 0; i < letter.length()-4;i++){

    fourLetter = letter.substring(i,i+4);
elementList.add(fourLetter);

    }
```

Then you need to read the dictionary words from file and insert into `set<String>`.

Then you can convert String array to List and iterate the list and check of `set.contains(listelement)`.

Comment: `split` only finds delimiters on which text should be split which prevents same part to be present in few results, so it can't be used here because letters should be reused in many tokens. Your code will split `abcdef` into `abcd` and `ef` while op wants `abcd` `bcde` `cdef`.

Comment: @Gator Other answer already shows you how to generate such words (tokens). Did you test it? If there is something unclear about it ask its author for clarification.

Comment: I updated my answer.Yes you are right we can not use split here.I hope ,updated answer will solve the problem.

Comment: @Vaibs, you updated your answer just as a copy paste of mine =D, congratz

Comment: @RafaelLima: your answer is right and I Upvoted to that.Also further explanation of my answer could help him to find the whole solution.I think you had not gone through my answer properly.